# Define a scala function in a play template

Tags: scala, playframework, playframework-2.0

I try to use a function in a play view template

```
@active(path: String):String = @{
       var active:String = ""
       if (request.path.startsWith(path)) {
           active = "class=\"active\""
       } 
       return active
}

<div class="container-fluid">
....
    <li @active("/page") ...>
```

The play compiler says that it can't find the value active. What's wrong here?

Comment: For one, the second @ symbol is unnecessary. Secondly, have you defined the @active function in its own file and/or imported it?

Comment: I moved it in its own file now. Like this it works. That's okay too because I need it in other files too.

Comment: @korefn: Actually, the second @ symbol tells Play that this is a block of what the Play documentation calls "pure" (i.e. Scala) code, as opposed to a section of HTML template. If he omitted that @, the function would return "var active:String ... etc." as literal text.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Try removing the return type of the function and move it to the top of your template. This works in my template (see also: [Playframework 2.0 define function in View Template](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10467101/playframework-2-0-define-function-in-view-template)):

```
@active(path: String) = @{
  if (request.path.startsWith(path))
    "class=\"active\""
  else
    ""
}
```